# Find location source using Fused Location Provider

Tags: android, geolocation

AFAIK, `fused location provider` can use network or gps data depending on different conditions. Is it possible to find which exact location data source (WiFi, Cellular, GPS) was used after getting location with `fused location provider`? All I want is to show some notification on screen about the source of location data, like it's done in `2Gis` app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No,

```
Fused location provider:
```

[The Fused Location Provider intelligently manages the underlying location technology and gives you the best location according to your needs.](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)

It may use combo of that data.